# Can I extract or construct as a Pandas dataframe the table with coefficient values etc. provided by the summary() method in statsmodels?

Tags: pandas, linear-regression, python-3.7, statsmodels

I have run an OLS model in statsmodels and I would like to have the table in the summary as a Pandas dataframe.

This is what I mean:

[image]

I would like the table within the red frame to be constructed / extracted and become a Pandas DataFrame.

My code up to that point was straightforward:

```
from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS

mod = OLS(endog = coded_design_poly_select.response.values, exog = coded_design_poly_select.iloc[:, :-1].values)

fitted_model = mod.fit()

fitted_model.summary()
```

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fitted_model` is in fact a `RegressionResults` object that stores all the regression results and you can access them via the corresponding [methods/attributes](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults).

For what you asked for, I believe the following code would work

```py
data = {'coef': fitted_model.params,
        'std err': fitted_model.bse,
        't': fitted_model.tvalues,
        'P>|t|': fitted_model.pvalues,
        '[0.025': fitted_model.conf_int()[0],
        '0.975]': fitted_model.conf_int()[1]}

pd.DataFrame(data).round(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this is from [`fitted_model.summary2()`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.summary2.html)

You can get a dataframe directly as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

np.random.seed(0)

n_sample = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, n_sample)
X = np.column_stack((x, x ** 2))
beta = np.array([1, 0.1, 10])
e = np.random.normal(size=n_sample)

X = sm.add_constant(X)
y = np.dot(X, beta) + e

model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()

res_df = results.summary2().tables[1]
print(res_df)
print(type(res_df))
```

This will print:

```py
           Coef.  Std.Err.           t          P>|t|     [0.025     0.975]
const   2.063084  0.275825    7.479687   3.364219e-11   1.515648   2.610520
x1     -0.447733  0.127479   -3.512193   6.764791e-04  -0.700744  -0.194721
x2     10.051800  0.012335  814.869057  7.714347e-188  10.027317  10.076282
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Which is a `Pandas.DataFrame`.

Note that this is an experimental feature, and its state has been [a long-standanding debate](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1573).

Answer (score 0):

Although [steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59725066/23143156) is probably the best/recommended way, here's another approach that doesn't require manually typing the column names:

```python
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

dat = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('Guerry', 'HistData').data
X = sm.add_constant(dat[['Literacy']])
results = sm.OLS(dat['Lottery'],X).fit()

# Convert the desired summary table to a numpy array
stats = np.array(results.summary().tables[1].data)

# Now convert to a DataFrame using the first row as header
# and first column as index
stats_df = pd.DataFrame(data=stats[1:,1:], index=stats[1:,0], columns=stats[0,1:])
stats_df
```

This gives:

|  | coef | std err | t | P>|t| | [0.025 | 0.975] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Intercept | 64.0896 | 6.265 | 10.23 | 0 | 51.631 | 76.548 |
| Literacy | -0.5245 | 0.146 | -3.59 | 0.001 | -0.815 | -0.234 |